# Getting recording files on FreePBX through API

Tags: freepbx

I have a bit of a problem with FreePBX API. To sum it, we have Asterisk/FreePBX setup in our intranet, and we have a website on another machine. Task is to show list of recordings in admin panel's orders page for respective order phone number on button click and be able to listen these recordings on said web-server. I have no problem with getting cdr data from FreePBX with GraphQL API, but I cannot find where I can get recording wav files itself in API (I do not have any access to asterisk server and our sysadmin doesn't want to make a shared folder or mount it. Understandable though). ARI doesn't help either, recordings go with FreePBX system (it's put into `/asterisk/monitor` folder, not `/asterisk/recordings`) and cannot be accessed through `/recordings/stored` endpoint.

Maybe I'm blind but GraphQL `fetchAllCdrs` and `fetchCdr` are only endpoints that have any relation to recordings, both return JSON with recording's data, including name, id, duration and much more, but I need file itself. Can someone tell me if I can get recording file and where (if yes ofc) through API? As I mentioned before, dances with file system or internal helper webserver is not something I want nor could do.

Comment: Presumably the API documentation has a list of available endpoints you can use? If it's not there, why would anyone here have any different answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write api which suite your best yourself.

There is API in /recordings/ but it is not perfect.

Authorization is via FreePBX users(cookies or see how different ways can be auth in FreePBX). After that to get file go

```
https://domain_name.yourserver/admin/config.php?display=cdr&action=download_audio&cdr_file=1679197133.30162
```

Where cdr_file is uniqueid of main cdr record.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need admin access to freepbx admin panel out there which I don't have, I've given only machine-to-machine app credentials and endpoints. Still, after some brawling, screams and talk with superiors I made our sysadmin create custom api on asterisk server and now I'm downloading files through it.

Comment: No you don't need. You can create user with access to cdr module only in authusers

Comment: How to auth to FreePBX? I tried basic auth but this didnt work

Request example 
curl --location 'http://myserver.com/admin/config.php?display=cdr&action=download_audio&cdr_file=1680588618.d6cdlwa%3B2' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic blabla=='

Comment: Default authorization type via coockies AUTHTYPE=database. If you want basic you have change in config.

Comment: I attempted this on a FreePBX 15 install and I'd get an empty response with no matter what cdr_file id I gave it (including nonexistent).

Does this depend on specific modules being installed? For this example, would a voicemail count as a recording, or is that separate?

Comment: Should not. Sorry, I not see how I can guess your debug issues. Voicemails are NOT listed via that interface. For voicemail there is another location and another web interface.